# Camel: transform to object and populate with Xpath value

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I have a response object that I want to return:

```
Response myResponse;

from(<step1>).to(<step2>).transform(constant(myResponse));
```

But I want to populate a response field with an XPath value against the output from step2 that would normally be done with:

```
 myResponse.setReturnValue(<string_value>);
```

I came up with the solution as below, hardcoding the unmarshalled XML and then marshalling back to the Response object, but I feel like there is a more elegant way:

```
from("").to("").setBody(xpath(<my-xpath>).stringResult())
 .setBody(simple("<Response><ReturnValue>${body}</ReturnValue></Response>"))
   convertBodyTo(Response.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [StringTemplate](http://camel.apache.org/stringtemplate.html) component. Make a template placed in the classpath that has the final XML with i.e.`<Response><ReturnValue>${body}</ReturnValue></Response>`

and invoke the string-template component that shall replace token ${body} with current message contained in exchange body. The route will then become

`from("").to("").setBody(xpath(<my-xpath>).stringResult())
 .to("string-template:MyResponse.tm")
   convertBodyTo(Response.class);`

Comment: Set the file to: <Response xmlns="http://inbound.smix.tapestry.cgi.com"><ReturnCode>OK</ReturnCode><CustomerOrderID>${property.orderID}</CustomerOrderID></Response> but getting: 1:10: 'xmlns' came as a complete surprise to me